# Spring Boot JPA @JoinTable with existing mapping table ignoring @GeneratedValue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to create a `ManyToMany` relationship between two entities `User` and `UserRole`.

I need some extra columns in the mapping table `UserToRoleMapping`, so I have created an entity for mapping table with the extra columns (like `createdDate` or `isActive`).

Now issue is that JPA ignores `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue` annotation on the mapping table `userRoleMappingId` column and creates a composite primary key using `userId, roleId`. That's alright. Since `userRoleMappingId` column is not primary key, I don't need it anymore, but as soon as I remove it JPA complains that it needs a column with `@Id` annotation.

Even if I leave it as it is, when saving `User` with some roles using `spring data repository for User`, it throws exception that `userRoleMappingId` column can not be null, as repository does not try to generate ID for mapping table, and it's set as `not null`.

Ideally I would like to have a primary key in mapping table with a sequence generator.

> What is the correct way to do create JoinTable with extra columns with
>   Entities ?

Here's a github repository with the sample code, to reproduce the issue.

https://github.com/ConsciousObserver/SpringBootJoinTableIssue.git

Following is the entity code

```java
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="USER_SEQ")
class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="USER_SEQ")
    private long userId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="UserRoleMapping", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="userId"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="roleId"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    /*getters and setters */
}

@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="ROLE_SEQ")
class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ROLE_SEQ")
    private long roleId;

    /*getters and setters */
}

@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="USER_ROLE_SEQ")
class UserRoleMapping {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="USER_ROLE_SEQ")
    private long userRoleMappingId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userId")
    private User user;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="roleId")
    private Role role;

    private Date createdDate;

    /*getters and setters */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The entity declarations do not reflect the required relationships mentioned in the post. They should be declared as follows:

> **User** entity

```
@Entity
public class User {
  @Id
  private long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
  private List<UserRole> roles;
}
```

> **UserRole** entity

```
@Entity
public class UserRole {
  @Id
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="userId")
  private User user;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="roleId")
  private Role role;
}
```

This will ensure that each `User` can have many `Role`s and similarly each `Role` can be assigned to many `User`s so that if `User`s and `Role`s are all looked at together, many-to-many mappings will be seen.

Comment: I need `@ManyToMany` relationship between `User` and `Role`, hence the requirement of `@JoinTable`. Please check the question again.

Comment: @11thdimension, you will get a `@ManyToMany` relationship with my answer (each user can have roles and each role can be assigned to many users). Go through the answer carefully and try it out. With a mapping table, `@ManyToMany` simply does not work, which seems to be confusing you.

Comment: In your entities where will the mapping between (userId, roleId) be stored ?

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that you're using `UserRole` as the mapping table, do I necessarily need to have name of mapping table in my User table ? Can't I directly get list of Roles ?

Comment: That should be straightforward to code in the `getRoles` method of the `User` class as `return roles.stream().map(UserRole::getRole).collect(Collectors::toList);` if you use Java 8. If you don't use Java 8, the method will be slightly longer but the same translation can be easily applied.

Comment: In case of list of Role directly I would probably get away with a single join query, however, in case of list of UserRoles, I would running a query for every UserRole->Role. Even if that's not the case wouldn't it be simpler just to leave it on the JPA to provide the list ?

Comment: @11thdimension, I didn't understand the comment.

Comment: I mean in case of `List<UserRole>` if I try to take `Role` from the `User` object, I will have to iterate over list of `UserRole` object, which will fire a query for every `UserRole` object, while in case of `List<Role>` there's a possibility that it will be done in one single join query. I haven't tried it yet, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: You can have `UserRole` fetch `Role`s eagerly if you are worried about multiple database queries. That way, whenever you fetch a `UserRole`, its `Role` will be already there. If you still have doubts, please ask them as separate questions.